# htaccess redirect Url does not work

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, cpanel, redirect

Please help me how can I redirect Url with the .htaccess file

```
Old Url: mydomain.com/? 
GID=0FFB340425F74356BEAB3817BD8E70F9&AKH=111&desc=%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1
New Url: mydomain.com/test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GID=0FFB340425F74356BEAB3817BD8E70F9
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} AKH=111
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} desc=%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1
RewriteRule (.*)  /test? [R=301,L]
```